# Error while installing openvswicth

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install OVS on my host machine running centOS.
While running the build file I am getting an error as:

> selinux-policy-devel is needed by Openvswictch.

I read about selinux and found out that they are set of rules and policies for the security engine.
How does it relate with OVS and how can I debug the error.

Comment: Install selinux-policy-devel : # `yum install selinux-policy-devel`